# Dropdown menu for categories

Tags: php, menus, page-template

When I use this code below

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'categories' )); ?>
```

I can make a new menu to list up for example alle categories in wordpress I created. I use it to list up all the categories in the middle of the page.

My question now: 
Is there an easy way to make a dropdown menu for every subcategory that exists? So when I click on a specific category its subcategories are showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you your desired result.

```
<?php 

$list_categories = get_categories( $args );
echo "<div class='container'>";
echo "<div class='productsubmenu'>";
echo "<ul>";

foreach ($list_categories as $cat)
{           

if($cat->category_parent == 0)
{
$category_id = $cat->term_id;

echo '<li class="parent '.$my.' "><a href="'.get_term_link( $cat ) . '">'.$cat->name.'</a>';


$args2 = array(
'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
'child_of' => 0,
'parent' => $category_id,
'orderby' => $orderby,
'show_count' => $show_count,
'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
'title_li' => $title,
'hide_empty' => $empty

);
$args = array(
'hierarchical' => 1,
'show_option_none' => '',
'hide_empty' => 1,
'parent' => $parent_cat_ID,
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);
$subcats = get_categories($args2);
echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';

foreach ($subcats as $sc) { 
    $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
    echo '<li class="" ><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
}


}
echo '</ul>';
echo "</li>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Do I need the  Woocommerce plugin for this?
A couple of variables are not defined and the else and brackets at the end doesn't make sence for me. It is not working unfortunately.

Comment: verry sorry martin i was in hurry i edited and tested code it's working now.